# Grails - Edit - does not retain the values when created

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, spring-tool-suite

Grails issue :

When clicking over the Edit in the following screen : Domain and Variable values does not seem to retain their values (When creating it, we are able to enter the values - Domain and Variable, but it does not retain the values when editing..

Clicking over EDIT in the following screen :

[image]

does not retain the values of domain and variable alone:

[image: Edit - not able to edit the domain and variable field]

## .gsp code below

```
    <tr>
            <td>Domain<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
            <td><g:if test="${isCreate}">
                    <g:select class="statSele" id="domain_name" name="domain_name" from="${com.datumrite.master.DomainMaster.list()}" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'Select Domain']" onchange="${remoteFunction(
                            action:'driveVariableFromDomain',
                            params:'\'id=\'+escape(this.value)',
                            update: 'variable_select'
                            )}"></g:select> <br>
                </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <input disabled="true" id="dN" name="name" type="text" style="margin-bottom:4px" value="${(data.domain_name instanceof String)?'':com.datumrite.master.DomainMaster.get(data.domain_name)}"  />
            </g:else>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Variable<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
            <td><g:if test="${isCreate}">
                    <span id="variable_select">
                    <g:select class="statSele" name="var_name" from="${[]}" value="${data?.var_name}" noSelection="['':'Select Variable']"></g:select></span> <br>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <input disabled="true" type="text" name="name" style="margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:5px" value="${data?.var_name}" />
            </g:else></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

<tr>
                <td>Condition<span style="color: red">*</span></td>
                <td><g:if test="${isCreate}">       
                    <g:select class="statSele" id="constrain_type" name="constrain_type"
                        from="${['Lesser than','Greater than','Lesser than nor Equal','Greater than nor Equal','Equal To','Not Equal To']}"
                        value="${data?.constrain_type}"  noSelection="['':'Select Condition']">
                    </g:select>
                </g:if>
                <g:else>
                    <input disabled="true" name="name" value="${data?.constrain_type}" type="text" style="margin-bottom:4px"/>
                </g:else></td>
            </tr>
```

And, I am using MySQL DB for the same.

can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: If you want to show the current value of `data.domain_name` in the dropdown then you should probably add the `value` attribute to the `select`-tag like you have done in the `select` for the `var_name`. What is the value of `isCreate`?

Comment: Are you saying that when you attempt to save the changes in the Subscriptions view the changes are not being persisted to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the subscription instance is passed when you click Edit link. (possibly under `<g:link...>` tag)  The gsp you've posted is for create view. Check your List of Subscription view. (possibly show.gsp)